# Has anyone been prosecuted for making/using malware?

Tags: computer-misuse-act

Has anyone been prosecuted under the Computer Misuse Act 1990 Section 3A for using or making malware in the UK? I have found example in the US, but none for the UK.

Comment: Is this assuming that whatever is written is contained to the UK and does not operate outside the UK? For example if you create a worm that infects the US, the US will build a case against you and ask for you to be extradited where you will be prosecuted.

Answer (score 3):

There is an excellent resource for looking at Computer Misuse Act cases:

http://www.computerevidence.co.uk/Cases/CMA.htm

There have been several cases where people have created DoS tools, botnet software, or credential stealing malware and used them.

For example, web designer Simon Vallor created Gokar, Redesi, Admirer mass mailing viruses that infected 22,000 PCs worldwide. Defendant pleaded guilty, convicted and sentenced to two years jail. [BBC news story](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/wales/2678773.stm)